# How to put an html inside a Ext.each() and render the value inside it- EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to render a span inside a forEach loop . I'm doing it this way:

```
var data = [5, 78, 8, 9, 6, 5];

render: function(data) {
  return [
    '<div>'
    Ext.util.Format.ellipsis(this.name, 48),
    '<span>',
    Ext.each(data, function(ct) {
      Ext.util.Format.number(ct, '0,000')
    }),
    '</span>',
    '</div>'
  ].join('');
}
```

however the above code is not rendering any value inside the  element, if I debug it, I see the value inside ct, but while rendering nothing displays inside . Any idea how to put an html inside for loop using EXTJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var data = [5, 78, 8];
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        new Ext.panel.Panel({
            renderTo: document.body,
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            html: data.map((x) => {
                return `<div>
                    <span>Some Name: </span>
                    <span>${Ext.util.Format.number(x, '0,000')}</span>
                </div>`
            }),
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Seems to work fine in [this demo Sencha's Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2k3f)

Comment: Thank you @Akrion, it does show in the list, however I was trying to get a list of <span>s (sorry for not mentioning it before), but something http://jsfiddle.net/qhapgvf0/ and that would be rendered as rows, is this possible with the approach you suggested? Thanks!

Comment: I tried: return (values.map((x) => '<span>'Ext.util.Format.number(x, '0,000')'</span>')) but it gives error:  " SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", not sure where is this missing?

Comment: I updated the sencha fiddle as well as the example above. It is more related to what you are trying to do. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help, just to know is it necessary to use Ext.panel for this? Can't this be rendered with simply inside a 'div' like in the question?

Comment: I used `Ext.panel` so I can show the full working example in the sencha fiddle. The important part is the `html` part where we do the `data.map...` take that part and see if it works in your `return`